# Calcular el factorial en todo tipo de números

Tags: c#

Verán, me encuentro haciendo una librería de funciones matematicas basándome en las formulas que ya conocemos y he desarrollado una función llamada `Fact()` para calcular el factorial de un número, esta tiene dos limitaciones:

1. El factorial más alto que se puede calcular es 20 *(20!)* usando el tipo de dato `long` *(Entiendo la razón de esta)*.
2. Solo funciona con números enteros (8, 16, 32 o 64 bits).

Este es el código que llevo actualmente para los factoriales de números enteros:

```
public static long Fact(long a)
{
    if (a == 2) return a;
    return a * Fact(a - 1);
}
```

#### EDIT:

Actualmente leyendo sobre el tema, si, el factorial solo se calcula para números enteros positivos, pero utilizando la misma herramienta, la calculadora puede realizar esta operación en numeros con punto decimal, ejemplo:

```
fact(0.8) = 0.931383770980242...
```

Y que esto se puede lograr por medio de la implementación de la función gamma, la cual no tengo idea de como implementar.

**Mi duda es** ¿Cómo calcular el factorial de cualquier tipo de número que se introduzca por parametro a la función?

Comment: El concepto "factorial" solo es aplicable a números naturales (enteros positivos sin contar el 0).

Comment: Y ¿Cómo se llama cuando el número no es entero?

Comment: Pues "no entero". Puede ser racional, real, complejo...

Comment: Me lo voy a inventar... pero "creo" que lo que buscas, es crear una "template"

Comment: No, Sir. Acabando de _leer_ sobre el calculo en numeros _"no enteros"_ me topé con la función gamma, busco la forma de implementar algo como eso en el algoritmo sin perder la recursividad, para poder calcular el _"factorial"_ de números que no son enteros. A ver si me expresé correctamente xD

Comment: Como dice @ArnauCastellví solo está definido para números naturales. Fin del asunto. Si aceptas como parámetro un long deberás validar dentro de tu método que sea un número entero positivo o de lo contrario lanzar una excepción: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial

Comment: Mirate mi respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Parece que he entendido la pregunta al revés. Para calcular factorial de números decimales (con gamma) no es fácil; en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454866/1468942) utilizando la [técnica de Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation) :

```
var g = 7;
var C = [0.99999999999980993, 676.5203681218851, -1259.1392167224028,771.32342877765313, -176.61502916214059, 12.507343278686905, -0.13857109526572012, 9.9843695780195716e-6, 1.5056327351493116e-7];

function gamma(z) {

    if (z < 0.5) return Math.PI / (Math.sin(Math.PI * z) * gamma(1 - z));
    else {
        z -= 1;

        var x = C[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < g + 2; i++)
        x += C[i] / (z + i);

        var t = z + g + 0.5;
        return Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * Math.pow(t, (z + 0.5)) * Math.exp(-t) * x;
    }
}
```

POST ANTIGUO:

Buenas; para calcular factoriales en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16583824/1468942) ponen un código recursivo que va genial:

```
long Factorial(long i)
{
    if (i <= 1)
        return 1;
    return i * Factorial(i - 1);
}
```

Para satisfacer tus limitaciones; justo antes de llamar a la función `Factorial` debes:

```
if (i > 20 && i > 0) {
    //Informa que no puedes calcular más de 20
}
else {
    long f = Factorial(i)
}
```

Si lo prefieres hacer en bucle....

```
long numeroFactorial = ??;
long result = numeroFactorial ;

for (int i = 1; i < numeroFactorial ; i++)
{
    result = result * i;
}
```

No entiendo tu definición de número entero, me imagino que te refieres a los números naturales que lo de encima ya respeta.

Comment: Hombre, usar una función recursiva para calcular un factorial está bien si estás aprendiendo recursividad... ahora que para entornos reales es mejor sustituir la recursividad por un bucle...

Comment: @eferion lo dices de verdad? Des de mi punto de vista esto es mucho mejor que con un bucle (que te obliga a hacer la validación antes). Ahora edito la respuesta pero sicneramente no entiendo que pienses así.

Comment: Bueno, realmente no importa el asunto de si es mayor a 20 o no, ando buscando detalles para poder realizar lo mismo en números no enteros, así como la implementación de la función gamma en el código...

Comment: @NaCl Lo he entendido al revés.... creo que la pregunta no está 100% bien formulada.

Comment: Porfavor digame que debo arreglarle.

Comment: Una llamada recursiva implica N llamadas a funcion, teniendo cada una de esas llamadas su propia copia local de variables en la pila. Eso es mucho más trabajo computacionalmente hablando que meter un bucle, que implica únicamente una llamada a función y una sola copia de las variables locales. Además, con bucles no tienes que temer hacer un overflow de la pila :)

Comment: En ESO Estamos de acuerdo, pero para facer un factorial limitado (max 20 llamadas) me parecia bonito

Answer (score 0):

Para almacenar números arbitrariamente grandes puedes utilizar la estructura [System.Numerics.BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

```
public static BigInteger Fact(long a)
{
    if (a == 2) return a;
    return a * Fact(a - 1);
}
```

Sin embargo el factorial más grande que puedas calcular depende de la memoria disponible en la computadora y probablemente ni siquiera puedas acercarte la mayor valor tipo `long`. En ese caso lo mejor es usar un algoritmo de [aproximación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Approximations_of_factorial).